# How to handle in PHP the APNS switch from SSL3.0 to TLS?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, apns-php

For security issues on SSL3.0 APNS will remove support for SSL3.0 and then all providers supporting only SSL3.0 need now to support TLS.
In my case I was using a PHP provider set as follows:

```
        ...
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $certFilePath);      
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);                 
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile', 'entrust_2048_ca.cer');   

        $apnsServiceLocation = 'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195';   
        ...
```

I found the solution just modifying the url of the APNS service:

```
        $apnsServiceLocation = 'tls://gateway.push.apple.com:2195';
```

Comment: gateway.push.apple.com is a production server, it doesn't reject SSL 3.0 yet (till October 29). Did you try it using gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com? This one is development server and does not allow SSL 3.0 anymore.

Comment: @Slabko last time I tested like 5 hours ago, even `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com` still was accepting messages which used apns prefix `ssl://`